# Difference between sentences in meaning

Tags: sentence-usage

> 1) Your passing the exam will make your parents happy.
>
> 2) The fact that you will pass the exam will make your parents happy.
>
> 3) It will make your parents happy that you will pass the exam.
>
> 4)That you will pass the exam will make your parents happy.

Are any difference between sentences above? Or are they grammatically correct?

Comment: They're all perfectly *grammatical*, but #1 is the one you're most likely to encounter. Note that at least *some* people will either be unfamiliar with the ["**possessive** pronoun before gerund"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/), or feel it's a bit "formal" (so they'd say ***You** passing the exam will make your parents happy.*)

Comment: I don't think (4) is grammatical; in fact I only think (1) is any good.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Ooops! Missed that one. Yeah - should have ***will*** before ***make***, as per all the others. Depending on context though, #2 and #3 could certainly be at least "okay", if not actually *preferred* (#3 might require a pretty contrived context, though! :)

Comment: How does anybody know that the person being addressed **will** pass the exam?

Comment: I forgot add “will “ before “ make” I have just realized that.